# No USB drives recognized on my laptop

Tags: kernel, usb-drive, laptop, usb

I'm having an issue with my laptop, all USB that I plug on the only one USB input (other is USB-C) of my laptop are not recognized.

I'm using elementary OS with an updated kernel (I tried to go back to default kernel but don't change).

I know I have an error at laptop boot but don't know if it's important.

Error from `dmesg`:

```
acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
```

`lsusb` when the usb is plugged in

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b59a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 114,8G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0   3,9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

`dmesg | tail -m 20`

```
[   20.796225] audit_printk_skb: 27 callbacks suppressed
[   20.796228] audit: type=1400 audit(1475419830.853:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="docker-default" pid=2034 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.147449] bridge: automatic filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables has been deprecated. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   21.150390] Bridge firewalling registered
[   21.154004] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[   21.326738] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[   21.346499] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   21.394647] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[   21.438479] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
[   21.561802] fuse init (API version 7.25)
[   24.351159] wlp1s0: authenticate with fc:b4:e6:3b:12:de
[   24.360894] wlp1s0: send auth to fc:b4:e6:3b:12:de (try 1/3)
[   24.366061] wlp1s0: authenticated
[   24.366895] wlp1s0: associate with fc:b4:e6:3b:12:de (try 1/3)
[   24.368293] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from fc:b4:e6:3b:12:de (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=2)
[   24.371018] wlp1s0: associated
[   24.371053] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[   25.959305] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   25.959313] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   25.959321] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

I can provide something more just ask me. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was tlp package which disable my usb port.